# Why do I have to subtract for height of UINavigationBar twice to get UIWebView to be correct size?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uinavigationbar

I am using a UINavigationBar in my app with three different UIViewControllers. The RootViewController hides the navigation bar when its view is on top of the stack by implementing the following in RootViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:TRUE animated:TRUE];}
```

and

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];

[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:FALSE animated:TRUE];}
```

When firstViewController is pushed to the top, everything works just fine. In the IB, I told this view that it has a status bar and a navigation bar. All of its subviews (added in the IB) are laid out just as expected on the simulator and on the device.

However, when secondViewContoller is pushed to the top, things get weird. In the IB, I told the view that there was a status bar and a navigation bar just as before. I added a UIWebView to fill the remainder of the screen (verified dimensions of 320 x 416 in the IB) and it all looks correct in the IB. I ran the app on the simulator and my device, and the UIWebView runs behind the navigation bar as if it were 320 x 460.

To fix this problem, I added this code to SecondViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 44.0, 320.0, 372.0)]; }
```

And now it all looks fine when running on the simulator and the device. But this isn't right! The height really is 416, not 372. Why did I have to subtract the height of the UINavigationBar twice? My hack works, but I think there is something important that I'm missing here that I really need to understand. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure why you're having to subtract the height *twice*, but I can explain why you have to do it at all.

Basically, in `viewDidLoad`, your view controller and its associated view have no idea where they'll be used. This means that your view currently has no superview. If you set your frame before the view controller is presented modally, added to a navigation stack, or presented in a tab bar, the view is liable to get moved around and resized and all kinds of crazy stuff. The answer to this problem is to perform layout in `viewWillAppear:` instead:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    webView.frame = self.view.bounds;
}
```

That snippet of code will adjust the web view to fill the area taken by the view controller, and will execute immediately before presenting the view on screen. When it executes, `self.view` has already been adjusted to account for a navigation bar, tab bar, status bar, etc.

Comment: Okay, so I moved the line "[webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 44.0, 320.0, 372.0)];" to -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated, and suddenly the webView is too short, as it should be, so changing the size back to 372.0 worked. However, without this line somewhere, the height comes out to 460.0 despite the IB assuring me that it's 416.0. Still confused, but this helps a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @PengOne Do you have an autoresizing mask set up in Interface Builder? That might explain some of it – the view might be getting autoresized based on what's happening to its parent, and by setting the frame, you'd be overriding any automatic resizing that happened in the meantime.

Comment: I had fixed the edges so it wouldn't resize. I think you're correct, and that the problem was that I wasn't understanding the difference that viewDidLoad happens before the view knows where it's going. When I fixed the distances, it was w.r.t. the parent view, which wasn't yet determined. Thanks for the explanations! Very useful.